# Unable to manually trigger pipeline - Trigger button grayed out

Tags: azure-data-factory

The trigger button is grayed out and disabled.  I cannot select it.

Pipeline has been published and zero errors on validation.
Pipeline is running on a schedule with no errors, but want to run manually as needed.

Tried Edge and Chrome

[Pipeline-Before-Publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V86n3.png)

[Pipeline-After-Publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeeJ8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't repro on my side. Which browser do you use? Could you share a screenshot of the disabled trigger button?

It seems like a bug, here is a workaround: 
on top of the trigger button, right click and then left click inspect

[image: on top of the trigger button, right click and then left click insect]

find the trigger tag and remove disable
[image: find the trigger tag and remove disable]

What's your factory version? If it's preview (2018-07-01-preview), then publish/debug/trigger are all blocked. Please refresh the page and go to overview page, you will see a prompt dialog suggesting you move to GA version.

Comment: Added screenshots above.  Used Edge and Chrome.